# Replace NA with blank but keep class as numeric in R

Tags: r

I got a problem with NA values when I tried to format dataset for analysis with software [WOMBAT](http://didgeridoo.une.edu.au/km/wombat.php) which needs the missing value to be blank. My goal is to replace NA with blank, but keep the class of data as numeric. Thanks!

In the below, I used a simple example explained what I did and where I got problems.

```
# set testdata
testdata<- c(NA, 1.1, 2.1, 4.3, NA)
class(testdata) # numeric

# replace NA with blank
testdata[is.na(testdata)]<- ""

class(testdata) # here, class of testdata was changed to character

# change character to numeric with as.numeric()
testdata<- as.numeric(testdata)

class(testdata) # class was changed back to numeric, however, missing values came back... see below. 

table(is.na(testdata)) # 2 missing values came back
```

Comment: Please show us a numeric vector with a blank as one element.

Comment: Do you intend to output as text file then use it for WOMBAT software? Then maybe try `write.table(testdata, file = "myFile.txt", na = "")`

Comment: Thank you for your "kind answer". I got your point. @jogo

Comment: Thanks! Your answer works for me. @zx8754

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: vectors in R can't contain mixed classes. If you want numbers to be numeric, then missing values have to be NA. If you want missing values to be empty strings, then other values have to be characters.

However, it appears that you want to process data and output it for use with WOMBAT. In this case, the output is a plain ASCII text file. All that's required is that the text format be correct for WOMBAT - the class of the columns in R is not relevant if you are no longer in R.

So you need to read the WOMBAT manual [regarding input format](http://didgeridoo.une.edu.au/km/WOMBAT/WWW/manualse19.html), then use `write.table` to create the file. Look at `write.table` for the options. In particular, you will probably need `quote = FALSE` and `row.names = FALSE`.