# How to mutate columns in place but keep same column types in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, mutate

Mutate in place is working fine as I set multiple dataframe columns blank if another dataframe column is blank. However, the mutated columns' types are changed. How to do this without changing column types?

Starting with data1:

[image]

I get data2:

[image]

Any ideas how to do this without changing any column types? Perhaps save all column types before the mutate and then set them back after the mutate?

Here's my code to create data1 and mutate to data2:

```
options(stringsasfactors = FALSE)
col_1_ferment <- c(452,768,856,192,905,752) #numeric type
col_1_crutch <- c('15','34','56','49','28','37') #character type
col_1_grease <- c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE) #boolean type
col_1_pump <- as.factor(c("3","6","3","2","1","2")) #factor type
indicator_col <- c(2,NA,2,1,1,2) #numeric type
data1 <- data.frame(col_1_ferment, col_1_crutch, col_1_grease, col_1_pump, indicator_col, check.rows = TRUE)

data2 <- data1 %>% mutate(dplyr::across(starts_with("col_1_"), ~ ifelse(is.na(indicator_col), "", .x)))
```

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962246/replace-na-with-blank-but-keep-class-as-numeric-in-r

Comment: Any one have an idea how to get data2 in one mutate step, without having to get NAs as was suggested below?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NA` instead of `""`

```
data2 <- data1 %>% mutate(dplyr::across(starts_with("col_1_"), ~ ifelse(is.na(indicator_col), NA, .x)))

str(data2)

'data.frame':   6 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ col_1_ferment: num  452 NA 856 192 905 752
 $ col_1_crutch : chr  "15" NA "56" "49" ...
 $ col_1_grease : logi  TRUE NA FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
 $ col_1_pump   : int  3 NA 3 2 1 2
 $ indicator_col: num  2 NA 2 1 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks @Vinícius Félix. But I do not want NAs. Want exactly the same as data2 above, but the only difference to keep the same column types.